# Angular2 how to use the service in providers from packaged module into another module

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have an angular2 application with Core package and Host package. core package is used in host package.

I am developing an authentication service which is defined in core package. But i want to service to be used in host package. so that i can use authentication to the whole application.

I want to use the service defined in core package. Can anyone help how to achieve this?

UICore:

```
export class UICoreModule {

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: UICoreModule,
      providers: [
        AuthGuardService,
        AuthService
      ]
    };
  }
 }
```

after `npm link .\src` i do `npm link UI-Core` in the host folder.

Host:

```
 import { UICoreModule } from 'ui-core';

 @NgModule({
 imports:[
    UICoreModule
 ],
 providers:[
    //how to use the AuthService from UICoreModule 
 ]
 })
 export class HostModule { }
```

Thanks

Comment: My understanding is thay you don't need to do anything - you now have access to the providers of the imported module without having to separately inject them into your host class. What's happening when you try to access them by directly referencing them in the business logic of your class? I believe it should just work as you get access to the providers of an imported module.

Comment: Also what are core and host 'packages'? I'm not familiar with these

Comment: Have got two applications. Host is the one which has got all the root menus and other root styles. Core package is the application specific to a project. I build and link this core project and create a package and use it in the host. host application is what i do npm build:prod and deploy.

Comment: Thanks. Why are you trying to use forRoot? Your example isn't declaring any components, can you just create an ordinary module with providers declared as usual then import it? Then, the providers should be directly available to the module that utilise the core module.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the forRoot static that you have created

```
import { UICoreModule } from 'ui-core';
@NgModule({
  imports:[
    UICoreModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class HostModule { }
```

We lack your UICoreModule decorator to be certain of that but the global pattern is that :

If you want to create a module exporting multiple components/directives/pipes and service. You can create a forRoot static method ( forRoot name is just a convention ) that will export component AND provide your Injectable. If you do this you just have to remove the providers from the NgModule annotations.

So in your AppModule (or whatsoever MainModule) you will import your UICoreModule with the forRoot method (this will imported the component AND provide alls services), and if you only need components from UICoreModule in another module, just import it regularly ( without the forRoot call).
This way Injectable provided by UICoreModule will be instantiated only once (aka Singleton)

More details here ( [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) )

So if you have imported the the UICoreModule (with providers, aka with UICoreModule.forRoot ) you can just inject your services in any constructor with Dependencies Injection within your HostModule

```
 import { UICoreModule } from 'ui-core';
 @NgModule({
     imports:[
        UICoreModule.forRoot() // <- important
     ],
     declarations:[
        HostComponent // <- for example
     ],
 })
 export class HostModule {}

 <! ... inside your HostComponent ....>

 export class HostComponent {
      constrcutor(private authService: AuthService) {
           // to whatever you can with this.authService
      } 
 }
```

Comment: Hi Pierre this is helpful however we're only talking about utilising modules here, the OP isn't about components, which are a specific type of Angular directive - could you please clarify your answer to be specific to utilising multiple providers between modules only?

Comment: Since the UICoreModule is imported you have only to inject provided injectable in the component/directive/pipe/whatsoever constructor. Constructor(private authService: AuthService) {...}